# CHANGE TEXT IN HOVER WITH EFFECT

Tags: html, css

I want replace defult content with my custom content in a button on hover.

I found a good example here:

```
<iframe height='268' scrolling='no' src='//codepen.io/Jintos/embed/rolim/?height=268&theme-id=0&default-tab=result' frameborder='no' allowtransparency='true' allowfullscreen='true' style='width: 100%;'>See the Pen <a href='http://codepen.io/Jintos/pen/rolim/'>Change text on :hover and :active </a> by Jintos (<a href='http://codepen.io/Jintos'>@Jintos</a>) on <a href='http://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.
```

it works and new text comes from left to right.(with effect)

can please tell me how customized it with top to bottom?(instead of right to left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the full code of the pen.
For a top to bottom effect you have to change the initial position of the hidden text:

```
.button:before {
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-150%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-150%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-150%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-150%);
    transform: translate(0,-150%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out i believe this will help you...

```
<button class="button" type="button" data-hover="CLICK ME" data-active="I'M ACTIVE"><span>HOVER EFFECT</span></button>
```

custom handler are written for button as data-hover and you could easily change the test within,...